# Stereographic projection of the icosahedron and snub cube?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polyhedra

Using a steoreographic projection, the [three equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosahedralEquation.html) associated with the icosahedron with unit circumradius, inradius, and midradius (respectively) are,

$$f=z^{20} - 228z^{15} + 494z^{10} + 228z^5 + 1$$

$$H=z(z^{10} + 11z^5 - 1)$$

$$T=z^{30} + 522 z^{25} - 10005 z^{20} - 10005 z^{10} - 522 z^5 + 1$$

These obey the nice relationship,

$$f^3+1728H^5 = T^2$$

***Question***: What are the three corresponding equations for the ***snub cube***? Do they obey a similar relation?

Comment: The snub cube does not have an inscribed sphere tangent to all faces or a midsphere tangent to all edges. So how are inradius and midradius defined?